# Symbol 'type shapeless.LeftFolder' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

Quick help out on this. During compilation I get the following set of errors ;

```
Error:(38, 21) Symbol 'type shapeless.HListerAux' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value spray.routing.directives.ParamDefMagnet2.hla'.
Make sure that type HListerAux is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'ParamDefMagnet2.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shapeless.
          parameter('id) { id =>

Error:(38, 21) Symbol 'type shapeless.Poly.Case2' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'method spray.routing.directives.ParamDefMagnet2.MapReduce.from'.
Make sure that type Case2 is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'ParamDefMagnet2.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shapeless.Poly.
          parameter('id) { id =>

Error:(38, 21) Symbol 'type shapeless.PrependAux' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value spray.routing.directives.ParamDefMagnet2.MapReduce.ev'.
Make sure that type PrependAux is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'ParamDefMagnet2.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shapeless.
          parameter('id) { id =>

Error:(38, 21) Symbol 'type shapeless.HListerAux' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value spray.routing.directives.ParamDefMagnet2.hla'.
Make sure that type HListerAux is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'ParamDefMagnet2.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shapeless.
          parameter('id) { id =>
```

Although, in summary, the problem is with 'shapeless', a library which I have already included as a dependency as (with the resolvers),

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.2"
)
```

I would appreciate a suitable recommendation as a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know how to solve it, I met this problem before.
It is the **problem of Shapeless Versions**, read the following scentence carefully, and you will solve this problem.

*Shapeless Versions
If you want to use shapeless as well as spray-routing in your application you need to select the version of spray(-routing) that was built against the shapeless release which you’d like to use.
For shapeless 1.2.4 you should use spray 1.1.4, 1.2.4 or 1.3.4 and the spray-routing module.
shapeless 2.0.0 is not supported any more.
**For shapeless 2.3.0 you should use spray 1.3.4 (Scala 2.10 or Scala 2.11) and the spray-routing-shapeless23 module instead of spray-routing**.*

```
libraryDependencies ++= "io.spray" %% "spray-routing-shapeless23" % "1.3.4",
```